# Concatenate all possible strings using one entry per variable number of lists

Tags: list, lua

It's the variable number of lists that is confusing me. It's easy to (pseudo code)...

```
 for i=1 to list1_size
   for ii=1 to list2_size
     for iii=1 to list3_size
        results_list.add(list1[i]+list2[ii]+list3[iii])
```

... but I could do with a nudge in the right direction regarding how to do this with a varying number of lists.

I've started with getting a table of the number of entries in each list to work through and it does seem like a bit of recursion is required but from there I'm drawing a blank.

edit: To clarify, what I am looking for is...

Input: A varying number of lists/tables with a varying numbers of entries.

```
{"A","B","C"}  {"1","2","3","4"}  {"*","%"}
```

Output:

```
{"A1*", "A1%", "A2*", "A2%", "A3*", "A3%", "A4*", "A4%",
 "B1*", "B1%", "B2*", "B2%", "B3*", "B3%", "B4*", "B4%",
 "C1*", "C1%", "C2*", "C2%", "C3*", "C3%", "C4*", "C4%"}
```

Comment: It'd help if you provide a sample input, and the output you expect.

Comment: I want it to do the same as the pseudo code does with a fixed number of lists, but with a variable amount.  I'll add an example to make it more obvious. Ta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
local list_of_lists = {{"A","B","C"},  {"1","2","3","4"},  {"*","%"}}

local positions = {}
for i = 1, #list_of_lists do
   positions[i] = 1
end

local function increase_positions()
   for i = #list_of_lists, 1, -1 do
      positions[i] = positions[i] % #list_of_lists[i] + 1
      if positions[i] > 1 then return true end
   end
end

local function get_concatenated_selection()
   local selection = {}
   for i = 1, #list_of_lists do
      selection[i] = list_of_lists[i][positions[i]]
   end
   return table.concat(selection)
end

local result = {}
repeat
   table.insert(result, get_concatenated_selection())
until not increase_positions()
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, it works perfectly (as you know)!